# How to typcast an iterator to its original structure

Tags: c++, list, pointers, stl, iterator

```
        list<CPoint> l;

        l.push_back( CPoint(1,2) );
        l.push_back( CPoint(30,40) );
        l.push_back( CPoint(4,6) );
        l.push_back( CPoint(70,80) );

        CPoint * point = 0;

        for ( list<CPoint>::iterator iter = l.begin();
                iter != l.end();
                iter++)
        {
            cout << iter->x << " , "  << iter->y << endl;

            // compilation error, I can't typcast it like below?
            point  = (CPoint *) iter;
        }
```

The problem with above is that how to typcast the `iter` in the loop to the actual data structure pointer? That way I can write code like `point.x`, `point.y`to say the least.

The above is the demo code I wrote but in reality I have this code in a search function. If an item is found in the list, it will return pointer to that item otherwise NULL. In order to get that pointer back I need to dereference the iterator back to the underlying data structure pointer but how? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix your syntax error, you need to dereference iterator then take the address from the underneath object:

```
point  =  &*iter;
```

You'd better just use [std::find/std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and store the iterator which is returned from std::list.

```
auto it = std::find_if(l.begin(), l.end(), 
                       [](const CPoint& cp) { return cp.x == 1 && cp.y == 2; } );

if (it != l.end()) // test iterator to see is desired CPoint is found
{
    std::cout << (*it).x << " " << (*it).y << std::endl;
}
```